# ReadAsync blocks only once (one read) then it won't block again in loop

Tags: asynchronous, tcplistener

I'm new with async sockets, I'm writing a server that receives data from many clients and needs to reply, when I start my Listener Task it will block on the ReadAsync line and wait for a packet to be received but then after it loops it will not block again to wait for another packet and does not receive any more data, I don't think I should restart the TcpListener with every packet, I cannot figure out what I'm missing.

```
    private static async Task StartListener(int port)
    {
        var tcpListener = TcpListener.Create(port);
        TcpClient tcpClient;
        byte[] dataIn = new Byte[128];
        byte[] dataOut = new Byte[128];

        tcpListener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for clients...");
        tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("A Client has connected");
        var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        int read = 0;
        for (; ; )
        {
            try
            {
                read = await networkStream.ReadAsync(dataIn, 0, 128);

                dataOut = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$value=0");
                await networkStream.WriteAsync(dataOut, 0, 8);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception!");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, I now become aware the connection gets closed after the async write, I wasn't expecting this, If I loop from tcpListener.Start(); it will work but seems weird the connection gets closed by itself on write.

Comment: I think it may have to do with my client closing connection when the TX task is finished I'm trying to figure out how to keep the connection open if that is the case.

Comment: It all seems my server closes the connection after the WriteAsync line and I need to re-start the listener, that seems odd.